# How to access element of a dictionary in the loop?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, element

I am trying to make a model which will predict the values of the traffic timer that are defined in dictionary. The same problem is already done and simulated in MATLAB but I am getting below error in python while accessing the elements from the dictionary.

```
import random
q_len = {'less': random.randrange(0,8), 'medium': random.randrange(6,14), 
'long':random.randrange(12,30)}
peak_hours = {'very_light':random.randrange(0, 7.5), 'heavy_ 
 morn':random.randrange(7,11.5), 'medium':random.randrange(11,16.5), 
'heavy_eve':random.randrange(16,20.5), 'light':random.randrange(20,24.5)}
time_ext = {'more_decrease':random.randrange(-32 -8), 
'decrease':random.randrange(-16 -1), 'do_not_change':random.randrange(-8 
-0.5), 'increase':random.randrange(0, 16), 
'more_increase':random.randrange(8, 32)}
def traffic(queue_len, peak_hours):
#entry1 = float(input('Enter the value of length of queue: '))
#entry2 = float(input('Enter the value of peak_hr: '))
#if entry1 in q_len && entry2 in peak_hours:
        for i in iter.items in q_len:
            for j in iter.items in peak_hours:
                if queue_len is less & peak_hours is very_light:
                    time_ext=more_decrease
                elif queue_len is less & peak_hours is heavy_morn:
                    time_ext=decrease
                elif queue_len is less & peak_hours is medium:
                    time_ext=decrease
                elif queue_len is less & peak_hours is heavy_eve :
                    time_ext=decrease
                elif queue_len is less & peak_hours is light:
                    time_ext=more_decrease
                elif queue_len is medium & peak_hours is very_light:
                    time_ext=increase
                elif queue_len is medium & peak_hours is heavy_morn:
                    time_ext=increase
                elif queue_len is medium & peak_hours is medium:
                    time_ext=do_not_change
                elif queue_len is medium & peak_hours is heavy_eve:
                    time_ext=increase
                elif queue_len is medium & peak_hours is light:
                    time_ext=do_not_change
                elif queue_len is long & peak_hours is very_light:
                    time_ext=do_not_change
                elif queue_len is long & peak_hours is heavy_morn:
                    time_ext=more_increase
                elif queue_len is long & peak_hours is medium:
                    time_ext=increase
                elif queue_len is long & peak_hours is heavy_eve:
                    time_ext=more_increase
                else:
                    time_ext=increase
print(time_ext)
```

It should print the value of the time extension after taking input from the function but it is not printing the same. Please help if anyone knows the mistake I am doing.

Comment: "I am getting below error" You forgot to add the error. Is it `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` in line 4?

Comment: @Goyo error is as below:                                                                                                      raise ValueError("non-integer stop for randrange()")

ValueError: non-integer stop for randrange()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is because `randrange` only accepts integer (whole number) values.  The whole point is that it takes random values from a `range`, which again only supports integers.  So for example `random.randrange(0, 7.5)` isn't going to work because `7.5` isn't an integer (it has a decimal in it).  If you wanted a random number from `0` to `7.5` in `0.1` steps, you can just do `random.randrange(0, 75)/10`.

Answer (score 1):

For accessing a dict, two methods:

1. `q_len['less']`
2. `q_len.get('less','')`. Second arg its default in case key 'less' doesnt exists

Comment: Felix Martinez, I am still getting the error after changing the code.                                         for i in iter.__getattribute__ in q_len:

TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Comment: its throwing error below in this line:                                                                       def traffic(q_len, peak_hours):
    for i in iter.__getattribute__ in q_len:
        for j in iter.__getattribute__ in peak_hours:
            if q_len['less'] & peak_hours['very_light']:
                timer=time_ext['more_decrease']
            elif q_len['less'] & peak_hours['heavy_morn']:
                timer=time_ext['decrease']